# where can I download an asp.net mvc4 template for xamarin studio mac osx

Tags: xamarin

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing and retried stable and beta channels but only mvc2 is installed.

would servicestack mvc be an option or am I barking up the wrong tree?

Comment: looks like asp.net support in xamarin isn't going to get any love. it's all about mobile I think. http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2321/asp-net-mvc4-web-api-to-create-restful-webservice

Comment: perhaps I need to build monodevelop from GitHub for mvc projects.hmm

Answer (score 2):

From this [blog post](http://blog.xamarin.com/the-making-of-xamarin-studio/) , it looks like Xamarin Studio includes monoDevelop's features + mobile development features. So you should be able to install and use mvc4 on xamarin studio. Does [this](http://curtis.schlak.com/2013/09/29/setup-asp-net-mvc-4-on-monodevelop.html) help you ?

Answer (score 2):

I use [this template](http://www.cafe-encounter.net/p1319/run-asp-net-mvc4-on-mono-monodevelop-on-mac-the-c-template-project). Has been working form me for a while now.